# Including exact matches in WHERE .. LIKE '%input%'?

Tags: sql-server, search, wildcard, sql-like

The query looks like

```
SELECT TOP 10 order_number WHERE order_number LIKE '%input%';
```

Assuming input is 5 the result would include the order_number 0500.
Assuming input is 0500 the result would not include 0500, which would be the exact match and I need it in the result.

Any workarounds out there?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please don't yell in all caps as they are noise and will likely deprive you from good answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Input AS INT    
SET @Input = 5

SELECT TOP 10 order_number 
FROM Table
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,order_number) LIKE '%' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@Input) + '%';
```

Or better declare the input as VARCHAR so you do not convert later:

```
DECLARE @Input AS VARCHAR(10)
SET @Input = '5'

SELECT TOP 10 order_number 
FROM Table
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR,order_number) LIKE '%' + @Input + '%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value '0500' exists in your order_number column and your WHERE clause looks like:

```
WHERE order_number LIKE '%0500%'
```

Then the value '0500' will come back as a match.  LIKE with wildcards on both ends will return true for anything containing the value between the wildcards, including the value itself.

From the link below, the wildcard represents "Any string of 0 or more characters"

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Comment: I thought it should, but it didn't. However the solution from Giannis Paraskevopulos works.

Comment: I suppose it depends on the datatype of your order_number column, and your input parameter.  What are those types?